Derivatives of Weierstrass $\wp$ function .
I am working on a problem where I have to show that $\wp''$ is a quadratic in $\wp$. I know the the differential equation that $\wp$ satisfies. From there after taking derivatives of both of the sides I got the following
$\wp''(z)\wp'(z)=12\wp^2(z)\wp'(z)-g_2\wp'(z)$.
Now my main concern is that can I directly cancel the $\wp'(z)$ from both of the sides. For example we know there are three zeros of $\wp'$ in the fundamental domain.

$$
\wp''(z)\wp'(z)=12\wp^2(z)\wp'(z)-g_2\wp'(z)
$$
implies that
$$
\wp''(z) = 12\wp^2(z)-g_2 
$$
except possibly at the zeros and poles of $\wp'$. But those are isolated, therefore the last identity holds everywhere.
